# Initial Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS Install - LUKS - headless/remote decrypt

Tags: boot, server, encryption, luks, yubikey

Installing Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS for the first time ever on a Beelink Mini PC (SEi12). Went for the most standard installation possible. Configured using a guided storage layout; i.e.

- Use entire disk
- Set up this disk as an LVM group
- Encrypt the LVM
  group with LUKS

Post install, moved the Mini PC down into my basement as I want to run it as headless. First issue I encountered was wondering why post install why no IP was being assigned by my DHCP, then realized, duh, I needed to decrypt. Started googling best ways to remotely decrypt, dropbear SSH, came across systemd-cryptenroll, noticed Yubikey support. However, despite all of my google and ChatGPT'ing; I cannot seem to figure out how to properly configure it for Yubikey decryption.

```
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                         7:0    0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1822
loop1                         7:1    0 111.9M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/24322
loop2                         7:2    0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/18357
nvme0n1                     259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1                 259:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                 259:2    0     2G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3                 259:3    0 462.7G  0 part
  └─dm_crypt-0              253:0    0 462.7G  0 crypt
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:1    0   100G  0 lvm   /
```

On boot, it specifically asks me to enter the passphrase to decrypt dm_crypt-0, however when using cryptenroll /dev/nvme0n1p3 is the only valid /dev, I can't target dm_crypt-0

I've been following this: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html specifically:

```
Example 3. FIDO2 Volume Unlocking Example

The FIDO2 logic allows using any compatible FIDO2 security token that implements the "hmac-secret" extension for unlocking an encrypted volume. Here's an example how to set up a FIDO2 security token for this purpose for a LUKS2 volume, using systemd-cryptenroll(1):

# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0

# Enroll the security token in the LUKS2 volume. Replace /dev/sdXn by the
# partition to use (e.g. /dev/sda1).
sudo systemd-cryptenroll --fido2-device=auto /dev/nvme0n1p3

# Test: Let's run systemd-cryptsetup to test if this worked.
sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach mytest /dev/nvme0n1p3 - fido2-device=auto

# If that worked, let's now add the same line persistently to /etc/crypttab,
# for the future.
sudo bash -c 'echo "mytest /dev/nvme0n1p3 - fido2-device=auto" >>/etc/crypttab'
```

```
sudo systemd-cryptenroll --fido2-device=auto /dev/nvme0n1p3
 Please enter current passphrase for disk /dev/nvme0n1p3: 
Initializing FIDO2 credential on security token.
 (Hint: This might require confirmation of user presence on security token.)
 Please enter security token PIN: 
Generating secret key on FIDO2 security token.
 In order to allow secret key generation, please confirm presence on security token.
New FIDO2 token enrolled as key slot 1.
sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach mytest /dev/nvme0n1p3 - fido2-device=auto
Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 512 bits for device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
Automatically discovered security FIDO2 token unlocks volume.
 Please enter security token PIN: *******
Asking FIDO2 token for authentication.
 Please confirm presence on security token to unlock.
Cannot use device /dev/nvme0n1p3 which is in use (already mapped or mounted).
Failed to activate with FIDO2 acquired key: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: @user535733 Yes, I want the system to be encrypted. I don't want to have to bring a keyboard/monitor down to my server rack in my basement to type in a passphrase to decrypt.